# Chrome developer tool Network tab - Remove unnecessary request and show only relative ones

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, redux

I am using React + Redux + Sagas building a web portal. When I switch from different pages on the web portal, I see all the requests stacking over each other in my Chrome developer tool Network tab. For example, when I open page A I see all the requests related to page A showing in the Network tab, then when I open page B, I see all the requests related to page B showing in the Network tab **meanwhile** the requests related to page A are also showing there.

I am wondering If there is a way in React or Redux to show only the relevant requests in the Network tab?
like when I open page A, only page A requests showing there. And when I open page B, only page B requests showing there?

Below is the pic showing that all requests related to different pages stacking over each other.

[image]

Comment: simply click the clear button :)

Comment: See that filter box at the top of the network tab... filter requests made by page A, or by page B, or clear the requests when switching pages. AFAIK there is no way for a specific page to control what/how the browser displays *all* the network requests being made per window/tab.